# How to disable automountServiceAccountToken in Kubernetes job template?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-jobs

We are using Azure AKS cluster and as per the Azure Advisor recommendations, we have to disable Automounting of api credentials from the Pods. but when we tried to enable this property in jobs template, the template is not accepting the value.

```
How to add automountServiceAccountToken: false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify either at service account level or pod level, if both specify then pod take precedence.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  serviceAccountName: build-robot
  automountServiceAccountToken: false
```

or at the service account level

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: build-robot
automountServiceAccountToken: false
```

[configure-service-account](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/)

So for job, it will be inside pod template as pod is nested template for the job.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pi-with-timeout
spec:
  backoffLimit: 5
  activeDeadlineSeconds: 100
  template:
    spec:
      automountServiceAccountToken: false
      containers:
      - name: pi
        image: perl:5.34.0
        command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)"]
      restartPolicy: Never
```

[job-pod-template](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#pod-template)